# Create 3x3 responsive layout with CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a 3x3 grid that shrinks boxes one under the other when on smaller screen. Boxes should be always the perfect square.

Also, the last two boxes (8 + 9) should be only one longer rectangle on larger screen, but take the same space as now. Is CSS grid a way to go here? Here's what I got:

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>join</div>
    <div>us</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.grid div:last-child:nth-child(3n - 1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>join us</div>

</div>
```

...and then add media query to make it responsive.

**Edit:**

What I did is -

1. changed height of `.grid div` to 0 and added `padding-bottom: 100%` to make it a perfect square.
2. added `.grid div:last-child:nth-child(3n - 1)` to target the last child and make it fill the rest of the grid.

**Edit 2:**
Added media query.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make it a simple 3x3 grid, and also that code doesn't work properly when you resize to mobile. Only a few of the squares showed when I tried it.

I removed the `.grid div:last-child:nth-child(3n - 1)`from the CSS, and added an extra  element.

Got the working and tested grid after that.

```css
.grid {
    background: lightblue;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background: white;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>

</div>
```